# Deal with collections in model in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I've started to learn WPF\MVVM approach and get bit confused.
I've:

```
class ModelAAA {
    public List<Foo> Foos{get; protected set;}
    //..

    public void Boo()
    {
       //Some complex logic updating Foos
    }
}

class ViewModelAAA{

    private ModelAAA _modelAAA

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos{get; protected set;}

    public void ViewModelAAA(ModelAAA modelAAA)
    {
        this._modelAAA = modelAAA;
        this.Foos = new ObservableCollection(modelAAA.Foos)
    }

    public void Boo()
    {
       this._modelAAA.Boo();
       //What should I do here?
    }
}
```

So if I use `Boo` method of view model, what is proper view to update collection in ViewModel. I've got few ideas, but they all seems to by ugly. Should I manauly recreate\change viewModel `Foos` each time? As I understad `ObservableCollection` is not wrapper like object.

P.S. I'm want to make it whitout using `ObservableCollection` in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model does not need to use `ObservableCollection`, but has to notify your ViewModel that something changed in the Collection.

this creates a copy of your List, which is indeed observable, but is not changed at all after that:

```
this.Foos = new ObservableCollection(modelAAA.Foos);
```

I would not recommend to create a new ObservableCollection, each time the Model-Collection changed. Instead implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` in your Model-Collection and handle the events in your Viewmodel properly.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need manually change it, as this is `ObservableCollection`, but you are changing *original* collection and not observable one.

To notify listeners of your Observable you need to act on Observable itself.

Example:

```
public void Boo()
{
   this.Foos.Boo();

}
```

Comment: So, `ObservableCollection` is kind of wrapper?

Comment: `Boo` is method of model clas, but not of collection.

Comment: @xander27: mine was just an example, to give you an idea. You need to change ObservableCollection and *not* collection you constructed it from.